# How to insert the copied visible rows from the top into in exsisting data

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

how to insert the Copied rows into same exsisting data , i want to insert that rows which i copied in the code given below in exsisting data and same sheet only

```
Name    Location    Salary
Sy      Hyd         12,000
Ay      Hyd         13,000
Raju    Hyd         15,000
```

i want to copy name location and salary from above table and insert the copied data into same above table from the top (Below header)

```
Sub Referral()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Sheets("Sheet3")

    'this is generic, you may need to adjust this based on your sheet and data needs
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .UsedRange.Offset(1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

End With

'goes to cell below last used cell in column A
Sheets("Sheet4").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues


Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'don't forget to turn on your ScreenUpdating again!

End Sub
```

Comment: We don't understand what you want to do exactly. Moreover, the code you took from somewhere else is already complete enough to do what you wish. Just try to understand the code and I'm sure you just have to change it a bit to suit your needs...

Comment: thanks for replying  JiheL , my requirement is what ever iam copying, that data i wnt to insert into same sheet rows from the top

Answer (score 0):

I just took your code and changed some stuff

```
Sub Referral()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With Activesheet
    .range(.cells(2,1),.cells(.cells(.rows.count,1).end(xlup).row,.cells(1,.columns.count).end(xltoleft).column)).Copy
    .Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 

End Sub
```